# How can I hide the page links in the pagination class in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

```
Prev 1 of 4 Next
```

I have tried setting the following `$config` option:

```
$config['num_links'] = 0;
```

But I get the following error:

> Your number of links must be a positive number.

My config options are set as:

```
    $config['base_url'] = "/browse/tag/$tid/";
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_items;
    $config['per_page'] = $max_items;
    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 0; # this doesn't work
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = " of $pages</span>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="previousnext">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

If I change `num_links` to 1, I obviously get:

```
Prev 1 2 of 4 3 Next
```

And if I turn off `display_pages` I get:

```
Prev Next
```

At this stage, I would like to avoid modding core code.

Comment: comment the line $config[num_links]

Comment: That will default to 3, and show `< 1 2 3 **4** 5 6 7 >`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's fine for you to have the digit links to exitst in HTML but not be displayed you may want to simply hide them using CSS.

Use `$config['num_tag_open']` to define an open tag with class, e.g.:

```
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<div class="hidden">';
```

And then simply add a CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [extend](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) the [Pagination Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) by creating a `MY_Pagination.php` file in the `application/libraries` directory and use it to override the `create_links()` function, which is responsible for echoing out the list of pages.

### MY_Pagination.php

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function create_links(){
        //copy and paste the logic from system/libraries/Pagination.php
        //but reimplement lines ~258-296 (CI 2.1.3) 
    }
}
```

By making the changes in your application directory and *extending* the core, you're safeguarding yourself against future core upgrades (from 2.1.3 to 3.0 for example).